# OCaml: Read a specific line in a file

Tags: ocaml

my problem is simple, i want to read the third line in a file. This is my code, I think it should work.

But it doesn't ... Can someone please explain for me why??

```
open Printf

let filename = "T:\\Soton Uni\\ok.txt"

let () =
    let ic = open_in filename in
    let line_counter = 0 in
      try
         while true; do
             line_counter = line_counter + 1;
             let line = input_line ic in
                if line_counter = 3 then
                   print_endline line;
         done;
      flush stdout;
      close_in ic
with e ->
close_in_noerr ic;;
```

Comment: As a complement to @gautamc's answer: `=` is the equality operator, so `line_counter = line_counter + 1;` tests if `line_counter` is equal to `line_counter + 1` and ignores the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in OCaml are never mutable — they can refer to mutable data, but what the variable points to can't be changed.

Therefore, the imperative style variable initialize and update can be written like this:

```
let line_counter = ref 0 in
  while true; do
    line_counter := !line_counter + 1
    if !line_counter = 3 then
      print .....
  done;
```

To initialize a variable using a reference:

```
let  var_name = ref value;
```

To dereference the value being refereed to by a variable:

```
!var_name
```

To update the value being refereed to by a variable:

```
var_name := !var_name + value
```